# CMD-file and task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I want to run CMD-file, as described [here](http://ipcfg.com/v.php?mod=tutorial&p=Examples).

I set run file every 5 minutes in the task scheduler. But when the scheduler runs the file - the window flashing. How to run CMD-file in background mode?

Installed Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full text and alternative methods see http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/invisible.txt:

> Save this one line of text as "invisible.vbs":
>
> ```
> CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
> ```
>
> To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:
>
> ```
> wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
> ```
>
> This is just a little dangerous because your batch file MUST be able
>   to close itself and MUST never produce an error which might require
>   user input. Otherwise the batch file will hang invisibly until system
>   shutdown or until someone kills it with the task manager.

Comment: You should copy in the relevant part.